# Get key values in JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the key values of each record in a JSON array when looping through it. Currently I have a simple JSON object like this:

```
 "users": {
    "key_11": {
      "text": "11"
    },
    "key_22": {
      "text": "22"
    },
    "key_33": {
      "text": "33"
    }
 }
```

My current script uses the 'map' method to convert this JSON objet to a loop-able array:

```
var user_profiles_array = $.map(user_profiles_string, function(el) { return el; });

for (var xt = 0; xt < user_profiles_array.length; xt++) {
    console.log(user_profiles_array[xt].text); //11 or 22 
}
```

My question is, how can I get the value for e.g: 'key_11' or 'key_22'?

Thanks!

Comment: `users.key_11.text` is the value of the "text" property of the "key_11" object.

Comment: Yes, but I need a way to get 'key_11' and 'key_22' and 'key_33' etc, not the value for the text property

Comment: The [`Object.keys()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of property names for a given object.

Comment: Using this function I get [0,1,2,3,4,5], but not [key_11, key_22, key_33]

Comment: `Object.keys(YOUR_OBJECT_VARIABLE.users)`. Look: https://jsfiddle.net/uxLug8pu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of all of your object's keys.  Once you have that array, you can use [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over it as necessary:

```
Object.keys(usersObject).forEach(function(key, keyIndex) {
  console.log("index:",keyIndex,"key:",key,"value:",usersObject[key]);
});
```

But!

your particular problem here is being caused by using `$.map` instead of `JSON.parse`.  `$.map` returns an array, so of course your keys are always going to be numerical array indices - `0`, `1`, `2`, and so on.  You're not going to be able to use hash keys to find things in the array returned by `$.map`.  Furthermore, judging by your variable names you're calling `$.map` on a *string* which is definitely not going to do what you want.  Assuming you figure that part out and you somehow get a valid JavaScript object, and you still need to use `$.map()` for some reason, what you can do is this:

```
// $.map will return an array...
$.map(user_profiles_object, function(objVal, objKey) {
    // ...and each item in that array will be an object with a
    // property named 'key' and a property named 'val'
    return {
      key: objKey,
      val: objVal
    };
}).forEach(function(arrayObj) {
    // now each item in the array created above will be an object
    // created by your callback function:
    console.log(arrayObj.key,":",arrayObj.val);
});
```

Comment: Is 'usersObject' the variable holding my converted array?

Comment: yes, but is there a reason you're using `$.map` and not [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) ?  because I think that's why you're seeing "0", "1", etc. as array indices instead of "key_11", "key_22", etc.

Comment: `$.map` is converting the object to an array - `JSON.parse` is just parses string JSON?

Comment: The reason I used $.map was because JSON.parse didn't work for me. I kept getting the following error:

'JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data'

I'm trying to parse a Firebase JSON file and maybe it's because their file is formatted a bit different?

Comment: your JSON isn't well-formed, I bet.  try wrapping your string in curly braces and then try parsing it:  `console.log(JSON.parse("{" + user_profiles_string + "}"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can also rely on Js's foreach.

```
// JSON string must be valid. Enclose your JSON in '{}' (curly braces);
var user_profiles_string =  '{ "users": { "key_11": { "text": "11" }, "key_22": { "text": "22" }, "key_33": { "text": "33" }}}';
var user_profiles_array  = JSON.parse(user_profiles_string); 

// For retrieval in loop, the Js foreach asigns the key to index param (i in this case).
for (i in user_profiles_array.users) {
    // i is the key of the user currently iterated.
    console.log('Key name is: ' + i);
    // Use i as the index to retrieve array value.
    console.log(user_profiles_array.users[i]);
}

// For direct retrieval using any given known key:
console.log(user_profiles_array.users['key_11']);
```